# Adding up values in excel dependent on another column

Tags: excel-formula

Is there a quick / easy way to create totals for each pupil in the scenario below? I regularly extract data from our MIS and need to find totals for each pupil and put them in column F?. I can't find a way to do this in the MIS and wonder if there is a simple way to do this in Excel?

[image: View snip of sheet here]

Comment: Welcome to SO! For better Q&As, you should share (i) (a sample of) your data (in form of code - not as an image), (ii) the desired output and ideally, if possible, (iii) what you've tried thusfar.

Comment: Look into SUMIFS()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your question doesn't have enough info but as I understood it...

I think you should make another sheet which has the people sur and first name

and then using (sumifs) formulas you can get the totals like this (in the second sheet next to sur and first names in column C:C)

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!E:E,Sheet1!A:A,A1,Sheet1!B:B,B1)
```